# How to mark Jenkins build as failure if any HTTP call failed in JMeter

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, jenkins-pipeline, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

We have developed API tests with JMeter . And also integrated JMeter with Jenkins. We are using batch command to run this through Jenkins:

```
jmeter -n -t ${workspace}//JMeter//APIAutomation.jmx -l ${workspace}//apireports//testlog.log -e -o ${workspace}//apireports
```

We are using the publishHTML method to publish the report:

We are able to see the report of all the API tests. But unfortunately whenever any API test fail, build is still passing. Is there any way by which we can fail the Jenkins build in case any API test failed?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter itself doesn't "fail" anything, the options are in:

1. Switch to [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin), it has feature to check the test results and mark the build as failed if there are failing requests
2. Switch to [JMeter Performance Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance/), it also has feature of marking builds as failed or unstable basing on various criteria
3. Switch to running your tests via [Taurus tool](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#Run-Existing-JMX-File), it has flexible [Pass/Fail Criteria subsystem](https://gettaurus.org/docs/PassFail/) allowing returning non-zero exit code if the criteria are not met
4. Add a [JSR223 Listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener) in your main Thread Group(s) and use the following code there:

   ```
   if (!prev.isSuccessful()) {
       props.put('failed', 'true')
   }
   ```

   then in [tearDown Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) add [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and put the following code there:

   ```
   if (props.get('failed') == 'true') {
       System.exit(1)
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Using 4th option I am able to fail the build in case any test failed. But one more problem occured due to this. Whenever there is failure in test publishHTML is not working. It only generated htmlpublisher-wrapper.html in the folder along with JMeter log file. But no index.html is there. But if the build succeed it properly generate API report. Is there any way by which we can avoid this?

Comment: The 4th option forcefully terminates the JVM before JMeter can generate the dashboard, if you want to proceed with it you need to split the command in two. 1. `jmeter -n -t ${workspace}//JMeter//APIAutomation.jmx -l ${workspace}//apireports//testlog.log` 2. `jmeter -g ${workspace}//apireports//testlog.log -o ${workspace}//apireports`